# Calculator in C

Tags: c, calculator

I've been trying to make a calculator in C and I am having some trouble cause when I said I wanted to choose again the program ends, or sometimes it works.

I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int xx;
  int Y, N;
  int a, b, c, d;
  int aa, bb, Sum, ee, ff, Multi;
  float cc, dd, Sub, gg, hh, Divi;

  printf("\n\nC a l c u l a t o r\n\n");
  printf("C h o o s e :\n\n");
  printf(" S u m    ( 1 )  \t");
  printf(" S u b t r a c t i o n    ( 2 )\n\n");
  printf(" M u l t i p l i c a t i o n    ( 3 )  \t");
  printf(" D i v i s i o n    ( 4 )\n\n");

  scanf("%d", &xx);
  
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  c = 3;
  d = 4;
  Y = 10;
  N = 20;

  if (a == xx)
  {
    printf("\n\nE n t e r   F i r s t    N u m b e r :\n");
    scanf("%d", &aa);

    printf("\n\nE n t e r   S e c o n d    N u m b e r :\n");
    scanf("%d", &bb);

    Sum = aa + bb;

    printf("%d + %d = %d", aa, bb, Sum);
    xx = xx - 1;
    printf("\n\nC h o o s e     a g a i n ?\n");
    printf("    ( Y e s     = =    S a y     1 0 !)\n");
    printf("    ( N o     = =    S a y     2 0 !)\n");
    scanf("%d", &xx);
    
    if (Y == xx)
    {
      printf("\n\nC h o o s e :\n\n");
      printf(" S u m    ( 1 )  \t");
      printf(" S u b t r a c t i o n    ( 2 )\n\n");
      printf(" M u l t i p l i c a t i o n    ( 3 )  \t");
      printf(" D i v i s i o n    ( 4 )\n\n");

      scanf("%d", &xx);
    }

    if (N == xx)
    {
      printf("\n\n F I N\n\n");
    }
  }
  
  if (b == xx)
  {
    printf("\n\nE n t e r   F i r s t    N u m b e r :\n");
    scanf("%f", &cc);

    printf("\n\nE n t e r   S e c o n d    N u m b e r :\n");
    scanf("%f", &dd);

    Sub = cc - dd;

    printf("%f - %f = %f", cc, dd, Sub);
    xx = xx - 2;
    printf("\n\nC h o o s e     a g a i n ?\n");
    printf("    ( Y e s     = =    S a y     1 0 !)\n");
    printf("    ( N o     = =    S a y     2 0 !)\n");
    scanf("%d", &xx);

    if (Y == xx)
    {
      printf("\n\nC h o o s e :\n\n");
      printf(" S u m    ( 1 )  \t");
      printf(" S u b t r a c t i o n    ( 2 )\n\n");
      printf(" M u l t i p l i c a t i o n    ( 3 )  \t");
      printf(" D i v i s i o n    ( 4 )\n\n");

      scanf("%d", &xx);
    }

    if (N == xx)
    {
      printf("\n\n F I N\n\n");
    }
  }

  if (c == xx)
  {
    printf("\n\nE n t e r   F i r s t    N u m b e r :\n");
    scanf("%d", &ee);

    printf("\n\nE n t e r   S e c o n d    N u m b e r :\n");
    scanf("%d", &ff);

    Multi = ee * ff;

    printf("%d x %d = %d", ee, ff, Multi);
    xx = xx - 3;
    printf("\n\nC h o o s e     a g a i n ?\n");
    printf("    ( Y e s     = =    S a y     1 0 !)\n");
    printf("    ( N o     = =    S a y     2 0 !)\n");
    scanf("%d", &xx);
        
    if (Y == xx)
    {
      printf("\n\nC h o o s e :\n\n");
      printf(" S u m    ( 1 )  \t");
      printf(" S u b t r a c t i o n    ( 2 )\n\n");
      printf(" M u l t i p l i c a t i o n    ( 3 )  \t");
      printf(" D i v i s i o n    ( 4 )\n\n");
      scanf("%d", &xx);
    }

    if (N == xx)
    {
      printf("\n\n F I N\n\n");
    }
  }

  if (d == xx)
  {
    printf("\n\nE n t e r   F i r s t    N u m b e r :\n");
    scanf("%f", &gg);

    printf("\n\nE n t e r   S e c o n d    N u m b e r :\n");
    scanf("%f", &hh);

    Divi = gg / hh;

    printf("%f / %f = %f", gg, hh, Divi);
    xx = xx - 4;
    printf("\n\nC h o o s e     a g a i n ?\n");
    printf("    ( Y e s     = =    S a y     1 0 !)\n");
    printf("    ( N o     = =    S a y     2 0 !)\n");
    scanf("%d", &xx);
        
    if (Y == xx)
    {
      printf("\n\nC h o o s e :\n\n");
      printf(" S u m    ( 1 )  \t");
      printf(" S u b t r a c t i o n    ( 2 )\n\n");
      printf(" M u l t i p l i c a t i o n    ( 3 )  \t");
      printf(" D i v i s i o n    ( 4 )\n\n");
      scanf("%d", &xx);
    }
    if (N == xx)
    {
      printf("\n\n F I N\n\n");
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried a lot of times trying to fix the code but it simply doesn't.

Comment: Why do you have spaces between all the letters?

Comment: Please use more meaningful variable names than `a` `b`, `c` `xx`, etc.

Comment: Aside: using `float` won't even make an accurate basic 8-digit calculator. Never use `float` without a clear reason why you cannot use `double`, the natural floating point type in C.

Comment: Try not repeating the same code so much. Asking whether you want to go again should be in the main loop, not inside the `if` block fior each operation.

Comment: You should tell us what the problem is. "fix the code" is a task not a question.

Comment: You should show the error your getting and what you expect this to do. This is unclear and not useful to diagnose.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `xx = xx - #`. You `scanf` for `xx` immediately after that math, so the result is overwritten.

Comment: Use constants.  Instead of `a == xx` do `if (xx == ADD)` then use an enum to define these `enum { ADD, SUBTRACT, ...}`

Comment: Perhaps you accidentally enter with a non-numeric character and the input stalls, it will never recover. **Please show the exact inputs that cause a problem.**

Comment: There is no loop. You can either do the four operations in order (+ - * /) or you can do a subset of them, but only once each. e.g. if you select `/` first, the program will then end after that.

Comment: Why are the two values for subtract and divide floats but for the other operations it's int?

Comment: On top of all of the other suggestions: you never check the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 4):

You have a lot of variables and repetition of code for no reason.  I realize that my answer behaves differently than original question but looking at the code I don't think you understand what you really want.  Start with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {
    ADD = 1,
    SUBTRACT,
    MULTIPLY,
    DIVIDE,
    YES = 10,
    NO = 20,
};

int main(void) {
    int choice;
    double values[2];

    for(;;) {
        printf(
            "\n\nC a l c u l a t o r\n\n"
            "C h o o s e :\n\n"
            " S u m    ( 1 )  \t"
            " S u b t r a c t i o n    ( 2 )\n\n"
            " M u l t i p l i c a t i o n    ( 3 )  \t"
            " D i v i s i o n    ( 4 )\n\n"
        );
        if(scanf(" %d", &choice) != 1) {
             printf("scanf failed\n");
             return 1;
        }
        printf("\n\nE n t e r   F i r s t    N u m b e r :\n");
        if(scanf("%lf", &values[0]) != 1) {
             printf("scanf failed\n");
             return 1;
        }
        printf("\n\nE n t e r   S e c o n d    N u m b e r :\n");
        if(scanf("%lf", &values[1]) != 1) {
             printf("scanf failed\n");
             return 1;
        }

        if (choice == ADD) {
            double result = values[0] + values[1];
            printf("%g + %g = %g", values[0], values[1], result);
        } else if(choice == SUBTRACT) {
            double result = values[0] - values[1];
            printf("%g - %g = %g", values[0], values[1], result);
        } else if(choice == MULTIPLY) {
            double result = values[0] * values[1];
            printf("%g * %g = %g", values[0], values[1], result);
        } else if(choice == DIVIDE) {
            double result = values[0] / values[1];
            printf("%g / %g = %g", values[0], values[1], result);
        }
        printf("\n\nC h o o s e     a g a i n ?\n");
        printf("    ( Y e s     = =    S a y     1 0 !)\n");
        printf("    ( N o     = =    S a y     2 0 !)\n");
        if(scanf("%d", &choice) != 1) {
             printf("scanf failed\n");
             return 1;
        }
        if(choice == NO)
            break;
    }
    printf("\n\n F I N\n\n");
}
```

The space between letters makes the prompt unnecessarily hard to read.

Consider changing the values you accept to be '+', '-', '*', '/' for the operators and 'y' and 'n' for the repeat prompts.  This would be much easier on for the user of your program.

Should something different happen if either the first or 2nd choice is wrong?  For instance, you could loop the prompt till you get a valid choice.

Comment: `printf("Cannot divide by zero\n");`... on most CPUs, floating point division by `0` produces an infinity that will be properly printed.

Comment: @chqrlie Do most CPUs also generate a trap that terminates the program?

Comment: yes and no: most CPUs generate a trap for integer division overflow (division by 0 and signed division of `INT_MIN`, `LONG_MIN` and `LLONG_MIN` by `-1`). This trap may or may not terminate the program and the shell may or may not report the termination cause.  The OP's code uses `float` arithmetics and yours `double` arithmetics, which more likely produces an infinity or a nan for division overflow.  Trying to catch floating point division overflow with a test on zero is vain as many other operand values can cause an overflow for this and other operations.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for the explanation.  Convinced and removed the 0 check.

Answer (score -1):

I Prefer using switch to if
because I find it simpler
the user types a string instead of 10 20
the code will error if the switch just has the full string

```
switch(var)
case'yes'
//code
break;
```

So it should catch only one letter which is y
like this

```
case'y':
```

so the switch would run the code.

Comment: The switch requires a block `{` and `}` and you single quotes is integer values while "yes" is a string.

Comment: You are describing some problem with the switch statement, even though OP doesn't even use it.